# Command doesn't work, No error, and bot doesn't crash

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need some help please,

When I click on the button Submit, it doesn't do what I want it to, it doesn't show up with any errors, and the bot doesn't crash so I'm not sure how to fix it.

This has never happened to me before so I'm just wondering I'm someone could point me in the right direction.

Suggest.js :

```
    const { ButtonInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
    const DB = require('../Structures/Handlers/Schemas/SuggestDB');
    const { APPLICATIONID } = require("../Structures/config.json")
    const Embed1 = require('../Commands/Suggest/suggestion');

    module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    /**
    * 
    * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction
    */
   async execute(interaction) {
    if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
    const { guildId, customId, message } = interaction;

    DB.findOne({GuildID: guildId, MessageID: message.id}, async(err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!data) return interaction.reply({content: "No data was found in the database", ephemeral: true});

        const Embed = message.embeds[0];
        if(!Embed) return;

        switch(customId) {
            case "Submit" : {
                await guild.channels.cache
                .get(APPLICATIONID)
                .send({ embeds: [Embed1] });
            }
        }
    })
}
}
```

Suggestion.js

```
const { CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton, ButtonInteraction } 
= require("discord.js");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Handlers/Schemas/SuggestDB");

module.exports = {
name:"suggest",
description: "Suggest",
options: [
    {
        name: "suggestion",
        description: "Describe your suggestion",
        type: "STRING",
        required: true
    }
],
/**
 * 
 * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
 * @param {ButtonInteraction} interaction1
 */
async execute(interaction) {
    const { options, guildId, member, user } = interaction;

    const Suggestion = options.getString("suggestion");

    const Embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("AQUA")
    .setAuthor(user.tag, user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
    .addFields(
        {name: "Suggestion", value: Suggestion, inline: false}
    )
    .setTimestamp()

    const row = new MessageActionRow();
        row.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("Submit")
            .setLabel("Submit")
            .setStyle("PRIMARY")
            .setEmoji(""),
        )

        try {

            const M = await interaction.reply({embeds: [Embed1], components: [row], fetchReply: true});

            await DB.create({GuildID: guildId, MessageID: M.id, Details: [
                {
                    MemberID: member.id,
                    Suggestion: Suggestion
                }
            ]})
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
 },
};
```

Any help is appreciated.
If you need any more information / code files, just reply and I'll will add it straight away.

Comment: Sorry, so it's a suggestion bot, you do /suggestion <suggestion> and it lays it all out into a embed, under it i added a Submit button which i want it so when clicked, it send that embed into a different private channel.

If you need any more info, just ask :)

Comment: It would also help if you included some sample code that includes the Submit button-- just in case the problem lies there.

Comment: The submit button code is in the suggest.js , and suggestion.js.

Comment: try adding console.log(1) and console.log(2) etc.. everywhere on your code to see what parts are not read on your code because it's probably a `return;` you put somewhere that is the problem.